# How to make Apache Solr disregard the size of documents when calculating their relevancy scores

Tags: solr

Is the ability to force Solr to disregard the size of documents when calculating their relevancy scores during a search a feature that's already built into Solr, or, is it otherwise simple to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable length normalization by setting `omitNorms="true"` for the field in question. Be advised that this also disables index time boosts.

From [Field Type Definitions and Properties](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Field+Type+Definitions+and+Properties):

> **omitNorms**
>   If true, omits the norms associated with this field (this disables length normalization and index-time boosting for the field, and saves some memory). Defaults to true for all primitive (non-analyzed) field types, such as int, float, data, bool, and string. Only full-text fields or fields that need an index-time boost need norms.

Comment: so disabling length normalization means the same thing as ignoring document size?

Comment: I'm not familiar with any inherent boost for document size, only for field length. Do you have any reference for the document size boost?

Comment: when i think of the word boost, i think of it as meaning to increase something. what does boost mean as your using it? because as far as i know, i'm not asking to boost anything.

Comment: Well, 'boost' would mean that the score gets higher (the score is increased because of the size of the _document_), which is not something that I've heard of Solr doing - so I'm just trying to find out what you're seeing to further adjust my suggestion.

Comment: ok. i'm not that familiar with the way lucene scores the documents, so correct me if i'm wrong. if my query is "tom sawyer" and there's two documents, each with one field, and both contain one occurrence each of the words "tom" and "sawyer", but one document is 25 words long and the other is 50 words long, will the shorter one have a higher relevancy score than the longer one?

Comment: No, not that I know of - you're the one saying that _document size_ matter. A _document_ in Lucene/Solr terminology is the complete set of fields - a distinct object. The only difference I know of is that the term in a shorter _field length_ (meaning that the word is "more significant in this text") would be scored higher, which is what I posted an answer for.

Comment: i think in the context i'm using the word document it's pretty obvious that document is analogous with a field when a document only has one field. and it's also pretty obvious that i want to disregard the size of the document i.e document size should not matter. but just to make it indisputably obvious, what i want is to prevent field length from being a factor when calculating the score. are you saying that is what `omitNorms="true"` does?

Comment: Yes. As answered, `omitNorms` will result in the score not being affected by a longer field length. (If it were obvious, I wouldn't ask the question)